# Dynamic array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings

I have an array of pointers to strings.

```
char **array;
```

I declare it this way and not char *array[N] because this array won't have a static number of elements.

Declaring the array this way, I will probably have to realloc the sizeof it every time I add a new element (pointer to string).

```
int main(void)
{
    char **array;

    char *word = "lolol";
    char *word2 = "blabla";

    return 0;
}
```

Could you give me an example on how I should "create space" in the array in order to store pointers to these strings?

Comment: "I have an array of pointers to strings. " No, you have a pointer to a pointer to `char`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way of doing it is probably by making a `struct`

This way, you can resize it, and add as many strings as you want without needing to choose a specific size.

Note: setting the string_array's `capacity` and `size` to 0 is necessary for it to work.

You could do it by a function like this instead:

```
void load_array(string_array *array)
     {
     array->size = 0;
     array->capacity = 0;
     }
```

And call it like this:

```
load_array(&my_array);
```

Note, when getting the value from one of these arrays using `[]`, you must call it like this:

```
my_array.arr[index]
```

This is because you must refer to the pointer in the array struct, which is as `arr` (`char **`)

I have tested the below, and it works perfectly.

```
# include <stdio.h>

typedef struct string_array
    {
    char **arr;
    unsigned capacity, size;
    } string_array;

void add_to_array(string_array *array, char *str)
    {
    if(array->capacity == 0)
        {
        array->arr = (char **)malloc((array->capacity = 3) * sizeof(char *));
        array->arr[array->size++] = str;
        }
    else if(array->capacity == array->size)
        {
        array->arr = (char **)realloc(array->arr, (array->capacity *= 1.5) * sizeof(char *));
        array->arr[array->size++] = str;
        }
    else
        {
        array->arr[array->size++] = str;
        }
    }

int main(void)
    {
    char *str1 = "Hello World";
    char *str2 = "Hello World2";
    char *str3 = "Hello World3";
    char *str4 = "Hello World4";
    char *str5 = "Hello World5";
    string_array my_array;
    my_array.capacity = 0;
    my_array.size = 0;
    add_to_array(&my_array, str1);
    add_to_array(&my_array, str2);
    add_to_array(&my_array, str3);
    add_to_array(&my_array, str4);
    add_to_array(&my_array, str5);
    // and so on
    for (int i = 0; i < my_array.size; ++i)
        {
        printf(my_array.arr[i]);
        printf("\n");
        }
    free(my_array.arr);
    getchar(); // this means pressing enter closes the console
    return (0);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    size_t N = 2;
    char **array = malloc( N * sizeof( char * ) );

    if ( !array ) return 1;

    char *word = "lolol";
    char *word2 = "blabla";

    array[0] = word;
    array[1] = word2;

    char *word3 = "Hello";

    ++N;

    array = realloc( array, N * sizeof( char * ) );

    if ( !array ) return 2;

    array[2] = word3;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) puts( array[i] );

    free( array );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
lolol
blabla
Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply allocate some room for pointers in your array, and free it when you're done.

```
char *word = "lolol";
char *word2 = "blabla";

char** array = malloc(2*sizeof(char*));

array[0] = word;
array[1] = word2;

free(array);
```

You can change that `2*sizeof(char*)` to a `N*sizeof(char*)` if you want more elements.

Comment: and if i want to add another word?

Comment: @Joe He doesn't need to copy if he uses `realloc`, though.

Comment: @tux sorry, mental typo